# In Debian 10 how to verify that an apt-get package doesn't contains any viruses or any malicious code

Tags: debian, apt, security, docker

The below `Dockerfile` is written based on Debian 10 (buster) image

```
FROM node:12-buster

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install wkhtmltopdf -y

#...rest content
```

As you see above I need to install a package called `wkhtmltopdf` using `apt-get` command (with flag `-y` which accept any permissions that package asked for)

**My question is:** In Debian 10 (buster) what is the tool that I can use to verify that `wkhtmltopdf` (an `apt-get` package) doesn't contains any viruses or any malicious code

**If you wondering why I need to do that verification:**

Because the container which built using the `Dockerfile` contains sensitive data and also it can communicate with other containers like `mysql` databse container and other external https resources.

So if package `wkhtmltopdf` contains any viruses or any malicious code that means hacker can steal database data and users sensitive information and other important things...

Comment: What exactly will it take for you to be assured that it is safe?

Comment: @muru To ensure that database data and other sensitive data will not being steal by hacker.

Comment: @muru By safe, I mean it doesn't includes any viruses or any malicious code.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: To expand on what @muru is asking. Let us start with "how do you determine that the host is safe?"

Comment: Does `-y` make it un-safe?

Comment: @muru, @ctrl-alt-delor Two reasons let me think about it as unsafe package, the first one that the source of package is not public so we cannot ensure that its code doesn't contain any viruses or any malicious code. the second reason `-y` flag however if I remove it docker will exit without install the package

Comment: 1st Having the source does not make it safe, unless you audit the source code, and find a way to ensure that it was built from the source that you audited. 2nd You did not yet answer my question about `-y`.

Comment: Are you saying that your concern is in validating the package `wkhtmltopdf`, However you are happy with a base system, and the host?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes I think `-y` will make it unsafe, because it will put my app in dangerous situation if it accept unsafe unneeded  permissions

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I trust the host  provider and system and docker I trust everything except `wkhtmltopdf` package. my question is how I can check that `wkhtmltopdf` package doesn't contain any viruses or any malicious code

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes my concern is in validating the package `wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: fwiw, this might help https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/wkhtmltopdf => https://packages.debian.org/src:wkhtmltopdf, https://salsa.debian.org/kolter/wkhtmltopdf.git , https://tests.reproducible-builds.org/debian/rb-pkg/wkhtmltopdf.html (and https://snapshot.debian.org/ to get all the exact versions)

Comment: @A.B thanks for helping, but is this https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/wkhtmltopdf means that `wkhtmltopdf` package was checked and verified by debian team?

Comment: That means you can check that debian did what it did. As for testing. I'm sure somewhere there must be written whatever you get comes without any warranty, can't tell where.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the `wkhtmltopdf` package is indeed available and you should be able to read it or build it yourself to determine if it is free of malicious code.

The [Debain package page](https://packages.debian.org/buster/wkhtmltopdf) has links to both the [original sources](http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf_0.12.5.orig.tar.gz) and the [Debian modified sources](http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf_0.12.5-1.debian.tar.xz).  I also found a GitHub repository that claims to have the [official source code](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf).

Regarding security, I would be much more worried about the warning "Do not use wkhtmltopdf with any untrusted HTML" from their [status page](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/status.html).  Even if you did validate that the package was non-malicious, the software itself seems to have bugs that might make it a security risk.

Personally, I would be more concerned about validating any `node` packages before worrying about something that is delivered with Debian.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with GracefulRestart. Yet if you need an antivirus for Debian 10, you can install `clamav` and use `clamscan` command to manually check files for viruses. I use it on Linux SMB/CIFS servers to track Windows viruses, it's quite effective.

Comment: But then, how would the OP know that the downloaded `clamav` package is free from malicious code ... ;) ?

Comment: You must be deluded to believe `clamav` is an antivirus. Firstly, last time I checked it's the absolute worst AV among all existing AV's. Secondly, it is unable to disassemble and analyze binary code which makes it completely worthless for new (Linux) malware. In short clamav is a bad joke. Relying on it is not just stupid, it's insane.

Comment: @AdminBee, depends on how deep down the rabbit hole you want to go. Let's review all kernel code :)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, surely it cannot be on par with the commercial alternatives. Actually on Linux systems I'm more afraid of rootkits or bad configuration than viruses. Yet on some smb servers I've installed it, it's got an acceptable success rate locating malware on files exchanged between users. Compared by testing using MS's AV, not thoroughly tested, just use it in companies that do not have any licenses for commercial products. So I do not consider stupid or insane, just better than nothing.

Comment: A false sense of moderate "security" is a **lot** worse than no security at all. When you know there's no security, you take measures to minimize risks. When there's something resembling "security" you might as well become lazy and believe you're protected.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov That's not a great argument.  Having a little protection and knowing you are basically not protected is surly better than having no protection and knowing you are not protected?